# fillText is not working in the Safari 3

Tags: html, canvas

I am using HTML5 `fillText` method of canvas in my coding.It is working file in IE6+,but it was not working in the Mozilla 3.0, then I have tried with `mozMeasureText` , after that it is working in mozilla 3.0, but now `fillText` is not working in the Safari 3+.

Is there any solution or patch for the Safari 3+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari 3 doesn't have fillText. (Safari 5 does)

You can use this library, though, to add it to Safari 3:

http://code.google.com/p/canvas-text/